# Why is my variable value not getting updated in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to update a variable based on the number of commits in git repo. I am correctly able to fetch the count but not able to update the variable for further use. Any idea what is going wrong.

```
variables:
  # Versioning
  # Version Format - 'VersionMajor.VersionMinor.VersionRelease.Revision'
  # Currently the Major, Minor and Minor are all constants
  - name: VersionMajorMinorRelease
    value: '1.0.1'
    
  # Revision will be calculated during pipeline run based on total commit counts for branch
  - name: VersionRevision
    value: ''
```

Further in job I am using variables as

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Set the build version
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.Action }}', 'BuildAndDeploy')
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        $commitCounts= $(git rev-list --count HEAD)
        $revision= $commitCounts.ToString()
        Write-Host "Revision = '$revision'"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VersionRevision]$revision"
        Write-Host "Version of App being built = '$(VersionMajorMinorRelease).$(VersionRevision)'"
```

Output printed -

```
Revision = '1660'
Version of App being built = '1.0.1.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is my variable value not getting updated in azure pipeline?

You could use the `VersionRevision` in next task.

According to the document [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash):

> When you use PowerShell and Bash scripts in your pipelines, it's often
> useful to be able to set variables that you can **then use in future
> tasks**.

That is reason why you able to fetch the count but not able to update the variable for further use, please try to echo it in next powershell task.